# How to avail "Forecasting: Methods and Application" dataset in Python?

Tags: python, r

I am using the book *Forecasting: Methods and Applications* by *Makridakis*, *Wheelwright* and *Hyndman*. I want to do the exercises along the way, but in Python, not R (as suggested in the book).

I do not know how to use R. I know that the datasets can be availed from an R package - `fma`. [This](http://pkg.robjhyndman.com/fma/index.html) is the link to the package.

Is there a possible script, in R or Python, which will allow me to download the datasets as `.csv` files? That way, I will be able to access them using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possibility:

```
## install and load package:
install.packages('fma')
library('fma')

## list example data of package fma:
data(package = 'fma')

## export single data as csv:
write.csv(cement, file = 'cement.csv')

## bulk export:
## data names are in `[,3]`rd column of list member "results"
## of `data(...)` output
for (data_name in data(package = 'fma')[['results']][,3]){
    write.csv(get(data_name), file = paste0(data_name, '.csv'))
}
```

*Edit:*

As Anirban noted, attaching the package `{fma}` exposes only a few datasets to the search path. The data can be obtained by cloning or downloading from [Rob J. Hyndman](https://github.com/robjhyndman)'s [source](https://github.com/robjhyndman/fma) (click green Code button and choose). Subfolder 'data' contains each dataset as an .rda file which can be `load()`ed and converted. (*Observe the licence conditions - [GPL3.0](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) - and acknowledge the authors' efforts anyway.*)

That said, you could load and convert the data like this:

```
setwd('path/to/fma-master/data')

for(data_name in dir()){
    cat(paste0('converting ', data_name, '... '))
    load(data_name)
    object_name <- (gsub('\\.rda','', data_name))
    write.csv(get(object_name),
              file = paste0(object_name,'.csv'),
              row.names = FALSE,
              append = FALSE ## overwrite file if exists
              )
}
```

Comment: How to write the csv file to any arbitrary custom location in the local drive?

Comment: besides, `data(package = 'fma')` is listing out only a few datasets out of all the ones that is shown in [the reference of fma](http://pkg.robjhyndman.com/fma/reference/index.html). Any ideas and solution for that?

Comment: Anirban, took me a while to figure this out (well, kind of). See edit to answer above.